# The use of verb tenses after "Thought"

Tags: tense, usage

I get a little confused with which verb tense to use after "Thought" is anyone able to help me.

I thought you had been at home.
I thought you were at home.
I thought you've been to Portugal.
I thought you had been to Portugal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"I thought..." takes a past tense, because it refers to the belief the speaker had *before* they learned differently. Your third example is not valid because *you have been* refers to the past as it affects the present. You could say, as an implied question, "I think you have been to Portugal?"

*I thought you were at home* - the speaker has just seen 'you' away from your home.

*I thought you had been at home yesterday* - the speaker has just learned that you were elsewhere.